# My application does not show while uploading a file from google drive/box etc

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I've created an application for file sharing .While I'm sharing a photo from gallery i can see my application in the list along with other apps.
But while i'm uploading some file from apps such as Google drive/box/file managers apps etc the app is not getting listed with other apps.
Please help me resolve this problem.

Thanks[image]

i gave the following as intent filter

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

It is listing my app when is share a file from gallery, but not from Google drive